# Mule:JDBC Select not working with #[variable] value

Tags: sql, jdbc, mule

I have this piece of code in my configuration where I am using a variable as part of the 'WHERE' clause to retrieve some values from a database.

```
    <logger message="ZIP CODE:#[zipcode] " level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>
    <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryTimeout="-1" 
     connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Get Information" queryKey="Select MKT">
    <jdbc-ee:query key="Select MKT" value="SELECT PRIMARY,SECONDARY FROM MKT 
     WHERE  MRZIP=#[zipcode]"/>
    </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint> 
    <logger message="VALUES Selected for MKTREL : #[message.payload]" 
    level="INFO" doc:name="logger"></logger>
```

This line does not give the output as in there are no results coming back from the DB.

```
    ZIP CODE:59718 
    INFO  2014-02-11 14:58:19,057 [[salesorderservice].SalesOrderProcess_pickOut.stage1.02]     
    INFO  2014-02-11 14:58:19,093 [[salesorderservice].SalesOrderProcess_pickOut.stage1.02]  
    : VALUES Selected for MKTREL : []
```

However when I hardcode the value I get the correct result:

```
    <jdbc-ee:query key="Select MKT" value="SELECT PRIMARY,SECONDARY FROM MKT 
     WHERE  MRZIP=59718"/>
```

Output is:

```
    VALUES Selected for MKTREL : [{PRIMARY=76, SECONDARY=45}]
```

Am I missing something here?

-S

Comment: This should work ok, could be a database related issue. What happens if you try MRZIP='59718'?

Comment: Thanks Anton, even I thought this should work but guess not.When I try MRZIP='59718' I get an error,org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: VALUES Selected for MKT : []
ERROR 2014-02-11 18:56:34,321 [[salesorderservice].SalesOrderProcess_pickOut.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Execution of the expression "message.payload[0].MRPMKT" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the zipcode variable to Integer, or use `WHERE  MRZIP=#[Integer.parseInt(zipcode)]`. I guess you have an issue with your database not liking quoted integers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast value in query to number by using DB specific function.

e.g. ORACLE/PLSQL and TO_NUMBER function:

```
<jdbc-ee:query
    key="Select MKT"
    value="SELECT PRIMARY,SECONDARY FROM MKT WHERE  MRZIP=TO_NUMBER(#[zipcode])"
/>
```